# How to iterate throught the values of an array using VueJS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, laravel

I am developing with Laravel 5.3 . I am using fractal as well. I also axios as Http Client to perform Ajax Requests.

If i send a get request to display all chairs api. I am returned with the display below:
[image]

I am using VueJS 2 to parse the values to the html view.

**ChairsController.php**

```
public function index()
{
    $chairs = Chair::paginate(25);
    // Return a collection of $chair with pagination
    return $this->response->withPaginator($chairs, new ChairTransformer());
}
```

**app-vue.js**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: { 
        chairs: []
    },
    mounted() {
        axios.get('http://l5.app:8000/api/v1/chairs').then(response => this.chairs = response.data);
    }
});
```

**getchairs.blade.php**

```
<div id="app">  
    <ul>
        <li v-for="chair in chairs">{{ color }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/app-vue.js"></script>
```

When i access getchairs.blade.php in the browser, there is error:

```
2/2
ErrorException in c5c35433.php line 72:
Use of undefined constant color - assumed 'color' (View: /home/vagrant/sites/l5/resources/views/dev/getchairs.blade.php)
```

How to **access the color value** and iterate through according to the total number of records? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As laravel blade template engine also uses curly braces you have to escape it with `@`, like this `@{{ color }}`. This way blade just ignores it and doesn't try to evaluate before vuejs. This applies not only to blade/vuejs situation but, for example, to blade/angular. Read ["Blade & JavaScript Frameworks"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks) section from documentation.

Answer (score 1):

blade & vue js use same syntax to run html in DOM. we have to initialze which is vue & blade. you have use `@{{ }}` when load vue output on DOM  like this

```
  <div id="app">
     <ul>
      <li v-for="chair in chairs">@{{ color }}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are able to refresh this page and see the code. Do you know how can i get the color json object and loop throught it?

Comment: have you try with Computed Properties in vue  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties

Comment: i'm going to check computed properties. thank you sir!